# Magento - How to get the Order ID and 2-letter state abbreviation of an order

Tags: php, magento, checkout, magento-1.9

So I have to send variables to an affiliate website and they need the order id, price, 2-letter state abbriviation, and the country abbreviation. I have already got the price and country abbr. but I still need the order id and the 2-letter state abbreviation. The code I have right now is as follows:

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();//doesnt work
$amount = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();//works
$stateId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('region');//Gives full name of State
$countryId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('country_id');//works

echo " display: $order $amount $stateId $countryId";//prints out the variables
```

I have been looking on all the code on here for the order id but nothing has returned anything. So I'm wondering what I am doing wrong with that/why it is not printing out anything.

The second thing is that I am wondering if there is an easy way to get the 2-leter state abbreviation? I have also tried 'region_id" instead of 'region' but that just gives me the number code (not the letter code).

Answers to either of these problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the context where you are displaying this information? An order ID doesn’t get assigned to the quote until it is being converted into an order.

Comment: I just have it in the header.

Comment: If I am understanding you right, this will work when someone would complete the checkout but $order would be empty until then?

Comment: How are you supposed to be sending the data to your affiliate, and when does it need to be sent?

Comment: It is sent once the orders are placed. And they gave me code that I already put in, I just needed to get the actual values corresponding to the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to send this information through the `success.phtml` file as only in that file you will get that info and avoid sending order ids for uncompleted orders (failed paypal transactions etc.)

1) depending on your checkout method, you may or may not have the state code in your data.

So if you get the name of states by

```
$stateId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('region');
```

then add this code afterwards:

```
$states = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('US')->getRegions();//get list of states 
    foreach($states as $state){
        if($state[default_name] == $stateId){ //check if the names match
            echo $state[code]; //get code
        } 
    }
```

2) On success page

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
```

should work.

Comment: When I put this code in the success.phtml page the OrderId did work but then my other variables (amount, stateId, and countryId) were blank. Is there a way to get all four to work?

Comment: `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId); 
  $total = $order->getGrandTotal(); 
  $subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();` all of these should work

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the order loaded you can call 'region_code' or getRegionCode(). I'm using magento 1.9. Not sure if it is available in previous versions.